# Matlab Functions and arguments

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have a function defined as:

> function(f, df, x0)

where f is a function, df is its derivative, and x0 is an initial point. How do we defined f on the command line? Do you use an inline definition? What about df and x0? What if df is a gradient? Also if x0 is an ordered pair, how do you define it in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

To pass a function as a variable, you need to use a *function handle*. A simple way to demonstrate this is to use a function handle to an *anonymous function*. A simple anonymous function can be defined as follows:

```
handle = @(arglist)anonymous_function
```

So, to make an anonymous function that adds 2 numbers, you could do something like the following:

```
f = @(a,b)a+b;
```

You can use this like any other function

```
>> f(1,2)

ans =

     3
```

If df is just a simple numeric value, it can be defined as follows:

```
df = 0.4
```

To define a pair of values, you could do it like so:

```
X0=[1 2]
```

Finally, you can put it all together with this example function (put this in a file called myfunc) . . .

```
function out = myfunc(f,df,x0)

out = df * f(x0(1), x0(end));
```

Is this what you want? I was slightly confused by "x0 is an ordered pair".